# How to solve a Network Traffic Problem using Pulp?

Tags: python, pulp, game-theory

Considering the following network traffic models and assuming that there are 1000 drivers, how can we calculate the social optimum for the model, by assigning the number of drivers that uses each possible route.
[image: Network Model]

I know the problem can be solved by linear programming using Pulp. However, my code is broken.

```
from pulp import *

prob = LpProblem("Network",LpMinimize)
a = LpVariable('A',lowBound=0,upBound=None,cat=LpInteger)
b = LpVariable('B',lowBound=0,upBound=None,cat=LpInteger)
c = LpVariable('C',lowBound=0,upBound=None,cat=LpInteger)

# objective function
prob +=  a * (((a+b)/100) + 20 + 5) + b * (((a+b)/100) + 10 + ((b+c)/100)) + c * (10 + 20 + ((b+c)/100))

#constraints
prob += a + b + c == 1000

prob.solve()

print("Status: ", LpStatus[prob.status])
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name,'=',v.varValue)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied
```

**Solution:** 
ABCF = 201 
ABEF = 798 
ADEF = 1

Comment: In linear programming you cannot multiply variables together (hence the name linear), and in the objective function you multiply a, b and c. That is the cause of the error. Is that enough for you, or do you want to know how to reformulate the problem to remove all non-linearity? The problem formulation does correctly represent the problem, it is just not formulated linearly.

Comment: By non linear terms, you mean a^2, ab,... terms. If that's the case then, I am not able to reformulate the problem in linear format. Can you please tell how I can reformulate to remove the non-linearity with above equation.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by non-linear terms. It is a big limitation of linear programming. I can maybe take a look at the problem later to see if I can figure out a linear formulation, but that is not a trivial process and I can't see an immediate way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for removing the non-linear terms would be to replace the integer decision variables on the non-linear costed arcs with binary decision variables for each possible number of drivers along that arc (will scale badly - but no issue for this small problem).

Example code given below. Note that the solution this returns is different to the one you give in your question (I get `ABCF=250`, `ABEF=750`), I make this solution out to have objective value of 29375 VS the one you've quoted having cost of a little over 29399 - unless I've misunderstood?...

```
from pulp import *

prob = LpProblem("Network",LpMinimize)

nodes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

arc_costs = [[('A', 'D'), 10],
             [('B', 'C'), 20],
             [('B', 'E'), 10],
             [('D', 'E'), 20],
             [('C', 'F'), 5]]

ab_cost = LpVariable('ab_cost', lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat=LpContinuous)
ef_cost = LpVariable('ef_cost', lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat=LpContinuous)

# Binary variable == 1 iff number of drivers along arc = index value
ab_flow = LpVariable.dicts('ab_flow', range(1001), cat=LpBinary)
ef_flow = LpVariable.dicts('ef_flow', range(1001), cat=LpBinary)

# Variables to contain the selected Number of drivers
ab_flow_val = LpVariable('ab_flow_val', lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat=LpContinuous)
ef_flow_val = LpVariable('ef_flow_val', lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat=LpContinuous)


arc_flow_val = LpVariable.dicts('arc_flow_val', [i[0] for i in arc_costs],
                             lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat=LpInteger)

# objective function
prob +=  lpSum([arc_flow_val[i]*j for i, j in arc_costs] + ab_cost + ef_cost)

#constraints

# costs for the non-linear costed arcs:
prob += ab_cost == lpSum([ab_flow[x]*((x**2)/100) for x in range(1001)])
prob += ef_cost == lpSum([ef_flow[x]*((x**2)/100) for x in range(1001)])

# only one of binary variables can be true for each of the non-linear arcs
prob += lpSum([ab_flow[i] for i in range(1001)]) == 1
prob += lpSum([ef_flow[i] for i in range(1001)]) == 1

# set flow values from the binary variables:
prob += ab_flow_val == lpSum([ab_flow[i]*i for i in range(1001)])
prob += ef_flow_val == lpSum([ef_flow[i]*i for i in range(1001)])

# 1000 must leave and 1000 must arrive
prob += ab_flow_val + arc_flow_val[('A', 'D')] == 1000
prob += arc_flow_val[('C', 'F')] + ef_flow_val == 1000

# Non terminal nodes must have flow balance
for n in nodes[1:-1]:
    if n == 'B':
        prob += ab_flow_val == arc_flow_val[('B', 'C')] + arc_flow_val[('B', 'E')]
    elif n == 'E':
        prob +=  arc_flow_val[('B', 'E')] + arc_flow_val[('D', 'E')] == ef_flow_val
    else:
        # flow into node == flow out of node
        prob += lpSum([arc_flow_val[i] for i in arc_flow_val.keys() if i[0] == n]) == lpSum([arc_flow_val[j] for j in arc_flow_val.keys() if j[1] == n])

prob.solve()

print("Status: ", LpStatus[prob.status])
for v in prob.variables():
    if ('_val' in v.name) or ('cost' in v.name):
        print(v.name,'=',v.varValue)
```